# filtering option in woocommerce in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I want to display the filtering for the woocommerce so please let me know if there is any option available for that.
I want to display product by brand vise using filter.

Answer (score 0):

go through below link thay might br helpful for you

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-widgets/